# Python won't let me add to my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime-error

I'm writing a code for gcse (not part of the test) where I have an external file with songs and the artist who made them, and given the first letters of each word, guess the song name correctly. In the code (below) I open the file and depending on if the line contains the song name or the artist name I add it to the songs{} or artists{} dictionary with the correct number, but I get this error message when I run it through my terminal:

File "task1gcse.py", line 21, in 
songs[f"Song {lineNumber}"] = (("{line}".format(line=line)).strip("\n")) # e.g. {'Song 4': 'Hey Jude'}
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object does not support item assignment

Here's the code:

```
# task 1 gcse 20 hr computing challenge
from random import *
import time


lineNumber = 0
artists = {}
artistNumber = 0
songs = {}
songNumber = 0
lines = {}


with open("songs.txt", "r") as songs: # opening the file
    for line in (songs):
        if line != "\n": # to ignore any blank lines
            lineNumber += 1
            lines[f"Line {lineNumber}"] = (("{line}".format(line=line)).strip("\n")) # so e.g. {'Line 2': 'John Lennon'}, but I won't be using this it's just for testing
            if lineNumber % 2 != 0: # if the line number is an even number, that line contains the name of a song
                songNumber += 1
                songs[f"Song {lineNumber}"] = (("{line}".format(line=line)).strip("\n")) # e.g. {'Song 4': 'Hey Jude'}
            elif lineNumber % 2 == 0: # if the line number is an odd number, that line contains the name of an artist
                artistNumber += 1
                artists[f"Artist {lineNumber}"] = (("{line}".format(line=line)).strip("\n")) # e.g. {'Artist 3': 'Avicii'}
        else:
            continue # if the line is blank; continue
```

This is weird because it worked for just the lineNumber dictionary... Please help, any would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to use the name `songs` for two different things - an open file, and a dict.  Rename one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `with open("songs.txt", "r") as songs: # opening the file`, you are overriding the already existent `songs` dictionary - so when you run `songs[f"Song {lineNumber}"] = ...`, you are trying to add that to the open file. Rename one of these variables to fix this problem. For example -

```
# task 1 gcse 20 hr computing challenge
from random import *
import time


lineNumber = 0
artists = {}
artistNumber = 0
songs = {}
songNumber = 0
lines = {}


with open("songs.txt", "r") as songs_file: # opening the file
    for line in (songs_file):
        if line != "\n": # to ignore any blank lines
            lineNumber += 1
            lines[f"Line {lineNumber}"] = (("{line}".format(line=line)).strip("\n")) # so e.g. {'Line 2': 'John Lennon'}, but I won't be using this it's just for testing
            if lineNumber % 2 != 0: # if the line number is an even number, that line contains the name of a song
                songNumber += 1
                songs[f"Song {lineNumber}"] = (("{line}".format(line=line)).strip("\n")) # e.g. {'Song 4': 'Hey Jude'}
            elif lineNumber % 2 == 0: # if the line number is an odd number, that line contains the name of an artist
                artistNumber += 1
                artists[f"Artist {lineNumber}"] = (("{line}".format(line=line)).strip("\n")) # e.g. {'Artist 3': 'Avicii'}
        else:
            continue # if the line is blank; continue
```